# How to write / read multi-line text in an XML file?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to save some application settings to an XML file. To do this, I use the following code in a single `Props.cs` file:

```
using System;
//надо добавить для работы класса
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;


namespace SettingWinForm
{
    //Класс определяющий какие нас&#129;тройки есть в программе
    public class PropsFields
    {
        public String XMLFileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\settings.xml";
        //Чтобы добавить настройку в программу просто добавьте туда строку вида -
        //public ТИП ИМЯ_ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ = значение_переменной_по_умолчанию;
        public String TextValue = @"File Settings";
        public DateTime DateValue = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
        public Decimal DecimalValue = 555;
        public Boolean BoolValue = true;
    }
    //Класс работы с настройками
    public class Props
    {
        public PropsFields Fields;

        public Props()
        {
            Fields = new PropsFields();
        }
        //Запись настроек в файл
        public void WriteXml()
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PropsFields));

            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Fields.XMLFileName);
            ser.Serialize(writer, Fields);
            writer.Close();
        }

        //Чтение настроек из файла
        public void ReadXml()
        {
            if (File.Exists(Fields.XMLFileName))
            {
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PropsFields));
                TextReader reader = new StreamReader(Fields.XMLFileName);
                Fields = ser.Deserialize(reader) as PropsFields;

                reader.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                //можно написать вывод сообщения если файла не существует
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a `Form` in a `Form1.cs` file that contains `textBox1`, `comboBox1`, `checkBox1`, and two `Button`s.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SettingWinForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        #region Settings action
        Props props = new Props(); //экземпляр класса с настройками 
        //Запись настроек
        private void writeSetting()
        {
           props.Fields.TextValue = textBox1.Text;
           props.Fields.TextValue = comboBox1.Text;
           props.Fields.BoolValue = checkBox1.Checked;     
           props.WriteXml();
        }

        private void readSetting()
        {
            props.ReadXml();

            textBox1.Text = props.Fields.TextValue;
            comboBox1.Text = props.Fields.TextValue;
            checkBox1.Checked = props.Fields.BoolValue;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Form Action
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }           
        #endregion

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            writeSetting(); 
        }

        private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            readSetting();
        }

        // Очистить 
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            comboBox1.Text = "";
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

How can I read and write multi-line text from `textBox1` to an XML file?

Comment: @JohnyL it would be helpful for others as well if you use english.

Comment: @vendettamit I offered to use [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement) to deal with XML. :)

Comment: @JohnyL I do not know much about C #, could you describe how this can be applied to my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have will work fine for saving and reading text from textBox1, whether single or multi-line. The problem in the code you've shown is you are saving both the textBox1 text AND then the comboBox1 text to the same field, `TextValue`. You are overwriting the first value with the second.

You need to create a new text field (i.e. `TextValue2`) for the comboBox text. Or maybe store the comboBox index value instead into `DecimalValue` if it is not editable.